# JPA with @Embeddable Primary Key generates JDBC INSERT for PK

Tags: jpa

Why am I getting a JDBC INSERT statement including the primary key from JPA?

> Caused by: 
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Cannot insert
>   explicit value for identity column in table 'ProductionDetail' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. {prepstmnt 6933355 **INSERT INTO**
>   ProductionDetail (BranchID, Date, DepartmentID, Price,
>   **ProductionDetailID**, Count, LastUpdated, Notes, LastUpdatedByUser) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=544, state=23000]

tomcat-8.5.3-tomee7 / EclipseLink JPA 2.1 / NetBeans 8.1 generated entity classes from existing database / NetBeans 8.1 generated session beans from entity classes

```
public class ProductionDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ProductionDetailPK productionDetailPK;

@Embeddable
public class ProductionDetailPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ProductionDetailID")
    private int productionDetailID;

public class UnmanagedClass implements Command {
    List<ProductionDetail> productionDetailsToInsert = new ArrayList<>();

    ProductionDetail productionDetailEntity;    //at this point ProductionDetailPK is null

//at this point ProductionDetailPK.ProductionDetailID defaults to 0, logically meaningless
ProductionDetailPK productionDetailPK = new ProductionDetailPK();    

        productionDetailPK.setBranchID(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("branchId")));
        productionDetailPK.setDepartmentID(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("department")));
        productionDetailPK.setDate(productionDate);
        productionDetailPK.setPrice(new BigDecimal(priceOrId));
        productionDetailEntity.setBranches(branches);
        productionDetailEntity.setDepartment(department);
        productionDetailEntity.setCount(Integer.parseInt(count));

        productionDetailEntity.setProductionDetailPK(productionDetailPK);

productionDetailsToInsert.add(productionDetailEntity);

insertProductionDetails(productionDetailsToInsert)
}

public void insertProductionDetails(List<ProductionDetail> ProductionDetailsList) {
    for (ProductionDetail productionDetail : ProductionDetailsList) {
        //getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        this.productionDetailFacade.create(productionDetail);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have a table where all the columns I'm setting plus the Identity column are part of a clustered constraint. JPA wants to set all the columns as part of the constraint. I'm pretty sure after I clean this up I'll be back on track. Thanks again for listening.